# How to restore Xcode App Target "Compile Sources" and "Link Binary with Libraries" entry?

Tags: xcode

I accidentally deleted all files inside those two entries in the App Target.

I have App Test target as well and App UI Test target, they both contain the same files that were in the App Target > Compile Sources and App Target > Link Binary with Libraries entry.

How do I restore them for my App Target?

[image: AppTarget]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!

The changes that I made through the Xcode UI section of the App target build phases are reflected in this file `project.pbxproj`. The file is usually under the directory of your project: `SampleiOSApp/SampleiOSApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

You can either `compare that file with a remote version of the file` in case you are using `GIT` to revert it back or in case you don't have your project under GIT you could try to recover it by opening the `project.pbxproj` file with `TextEdit` App in Mac and go to `File > Revert To > Browse All Versions..`

Hope this helps others as well!